# cpan2rpm does not seem to get installed Perl version

Tags: perl, cpan, rpm

I'm running on RHEL6, with RHEL's perl-5.10.1-130.el6_4 installed. I am trying to build some RPMs using cpan2rpm 2.028. Also, perl-version-0.77-130.el6_4 is installed. It's giving odd failures, saying the installed version of Perl is not new enough:

```
$ perl -

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
...
$ cpan2rpm --no-sign ExtUtils::MakeMaker

-- cpan2rpm - Ver: 2.028 --
Upgrade check
Fetch: HTTP

-- module: ExtUtils::MakeMaker --
Using cached URL: http://search.cpan.org//CPAN/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHWERN/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.64.tar.gz
Tarball found - not fetching
Metadata retrieval
Tarball extraction: [/root/rpm/SOURCES/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.64.tar.gz]
Unable to build module, the following dependencies have failed:
  perl >= 5.006
Stopped at /usr/bin/cpan2rpm line 491.
cannot remove path when cwd is /tmp/bj8upl6poj/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.64 for /tmp/bj8upl6poj:  at /usr/share/perl5/File/Temp.pm line 902
-- Done --
```

What's causing cpan2rpm not to know what version of perl is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why cpan2rpm doesn't work here. But I'll point out that the Red Hat team now use `cpanspec` to build all of their RPMs of CPAN modules. You might try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there a reason you want to build the rpm with cpan2rpm, you can simply install the Perl modules from the yum repository. For example:

```
# yum install perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker.x86_64

# rpm -q perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.55-130.el6_4.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it's fixed by installing Perldoc.

```
$ cpan Perldoc
```